# Composite Key WITH Operator IN and SubQuery

Tags: c#, linq

I have this inner join and I'm using LINQ to make my queries, how can I write this query with LINQ, I was seeking it on internet but I cant find something like.

```
 INNER JOIN e210mvp mvp
    ON mvp.codemp IN (1 , 2)
   AND mvp.codlot = dls.codlot
   AND mvp.datmov = (SELECT MIN(min.datmov) 
                       FROM e210mvp min
                      WHERE min.codemp = 1
                        AND min.codlot = mvp.codlot)
```

Thank you!

Comment: @Thiago let us know any efforts you have made

Comment: join mvp in ctx.e210mvp on new { dls.codlot } equals new { mvp.codlot }

I tried just this, because I dont know how I can do the IN operator OR this Subquery

Comment: I was seeking for IN operator on LINQ using Composite Key and SubQuey with Composite Key, but I cant find something that I can use

Comment: With no relation to the language, `mvp.codemp in (1,2)` can be translated to `mvp.codemp equals 1 or mvp.codemp equals 2`

Comment: this filter is a parameter that the user fills

Comment: LINQ `join` only supports equi-join, if you are doing other join conditions, you must move to `where`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave the equality tests in the `join` and move the non-equality tests to `where`. Note that the equality tests must involve the left hand side (or an expression involving it) equals the right hand side (or an expression involving it). Since you have `mvp` on both sides of the sub-select test, you can't leave it in the `join` operation.

```
join mvp in e210mvp on dls.codlot equals mvp.codlot
where new[] { 1, 2}.Contains(mvp.codemp) &&
      mvp.datmov == e210mvp.Where(min => min.codemp == 1 && min.codlot == mvp.codlot).Min(min => min.datmov)
```